# Excel Macro VB Run-time error: Automation Error

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I have a user who is trying to run this macro in Excel 2016.  It works sometimes, but other times it gives a debug error and locks her spreadsheet up.  I took a look at some of the other folks who had this issue, and a non-excel expert, I think I just don't quite get how VB coding works.  Any help would be appreciated.

Getting a VB

> Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':Automation error
>
> ### > The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

When you debug, this is what you get:

[image]

Comment: Instead of a screenshot of the code, can you copy/paste it (and format as code with the `{}` tags)?  Thanks!

Comment: You probably do not have the right tags either...VB.NET doesnt do macros.  Hover over the tags for guidance

Comment: Fully qualify your references and don't rely on Selection to be where you think it is.